# Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft' and cannot access the application '71dada86-21db-493b-93e4-1a902601f30f' in that tenant

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on web based application where I want to redirect the user to our application signup page when non-Azure AD user(Guest user) is trying to sign in through Azure AD SSO sign in page. Is there way to customize the Azure AD SSO sign in page and redirect the user except company branding. Or is it possible to build form based authentication page and integrate with Azure AD without using B2C?

We already have set the post_log_in_redirect_uri and post_log_out_redirect_uri and working as expected on login/logout.